# Is it possible to pass member variable names as arguments?

Tags: python

I was wondering if such a construction was possible in Python :

```
class A():
    def method1(self):
        print ('method 1')

    def method2(self):
        print ('method 2')


a = A()
call_method(a, 'method1')
call_method(a, 'method2')
```

Expected result :
method 1
method 2

How to define `call_method` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `getattr(a, 'method1')()`

Comment: Wonderful ! Thanks !